# cuda with mingw - updated

Tags: cuda, mingw, nvcc

We have been developing our code in linux, but would like to compile a windows executable. The old non-gpu version compiles just fine with mingw in windows, so I was hoping I'd be able to do the same with the CUDA version.

The strategy is to compile kernel code with nvcc in visual studio, and the rest with gcc in mingw.

So far, we easily compiled the .cu file (with the kernel and kernel launches) in visual studio. However, we still can't compile the c code in mingw. The c code contains cuda api calls such as `cudaMalloc` and cuda types such as `cudaEvent_t`, so we must include cuda.h and cuda_runtime.h. However, gcc gives warnings and errors for these headers, for example:

```
../include/host_defines.h:57:0: warning: "__cdecl" redefined
```

and

```
../include/vector_functions.h:127:14: error: 'short_4' has no member named 'x'
```

Any ideas on how we can include these headers and compile the c portion of the code?

Comment: Have you considered using the driver API?

Comment: @Matt no - how much work would it take to convert from the runtime api to the driver api?

Comment: If you have a lot of CUDA code it will take you a while to convert - the driver API is quite a lot more verbose than the runtime API. The driver API code would be easier to compile through mingw, since you call the driver through standard C functions. I can't tell you whether it is worth the pain of switching or not though!

Answer (score 2):

If you are really desperate there might be a way. The nvcc is really just a frontend for a bunch of compilers. It invokes g++ a lot to strip comments, separate device and host code, handle name mangling, link stuff back together, etc. (use `--verbose`) to get the details.

My idea is as follows: You should be able to compile the host code with mingw while compiling the device code to a fatbin on a linux machine (as I guess the device binary is host-machine independent). Afterwards link both parts of the code back together with mingw or use the driver API to load the fatbin dynamically. Disclaimer: Did not test!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it is impossible to use CUDA without MSVC. So, you need MSVC to make nvcc work, and you can compile CPU code with mingw and link everything together.

According to http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=30743

> "There are no current plans to support mingw."

Comment: On the other hand, if you don't absolutely insist on CUDA (i.e. if the non-proprietary OpenCL is "good enough"), that one works seamlessly with MinGW.

Comment: @Damon - any experience porting CUDA to opencl? I seem to recall that the syntax similar, if not exactly the same...

Comment: @Damon, really? Is there nvidia OpenCL which can be used with OpenCL?

Comment: There is a tool to help migration from CUDA to OpenCL http://gpgpu.org/2010/03/09/swan and there must be a lot of manuals, e.g. http://developer.amd.com/documentation/articles/pages/OpenCL-and-the-AMD-APP-SDK.aspx#four

Comment: @osgx - Yes I've seen that thread. At the same time, the nvcc manual specifically mentions flags for mingw and cygwin compilation. This indicates to me that, while not officially supported, someone has maybe succeeded?

Comment: @osgx - so the question still completely stands. Though in theory I understand what to do, I need to know for example how to link everything together in the end.

Comment: I took the import lib that comes with the ATI stream SDK (but the one from nVidia probably works just as good) and that worked without any issues on my nVidia card. I also tried some dynamic loader code from some Apple guy that I found on the internet which loads all the functions by hand, and replaced the whatever-it-is-called with GetProcAddress. That, too, worked (though I later figured that it's silly to be too flexible, today one can simply make OpenCL a requirement). As for CUDA-CL I have no idea, I've heard that it is similar too, but I have no experience with CUDA at all.